# How to calculate the optimal weights and bias in SVM (by hand)

Tags: svm, bias, weights

I've been trying to solve the following exercise:

-> Consider a dataset with two points in 1D: (x1 = 0, y1 = −1) and (x2 = √2, y2 = 1).
Consider also the mapping to 3D φ(x) = [1, √2x, x2].

a) Find the optimal weights w0. Hint: recall that the separation margin between the two
classes is ρ = 2/||w0k||

b) Find the optimal bias b0.

c) Write the discriminant fucntion g(x) = wT0 φ(x) + b0 as an explicit function of x.
Note: If you did not solve the two previous points, use the literals corresponding to
w0 and b0.

However, I cannot find a proper way to find the optimal parameters. Most equations I find require additional information. Could you help in this matter?